# Serving Angular app with specific location with Nginx not routing properly

Tags: angular, nginx

I definitely lack some knowledge on Nginx and all this deployment stuff... I'm trying to serve an angular when a specific location is met, so inside my server configuration on the `default.conf` I'm trying to do it like this:

```
location /app/ {
   index index.html;
   alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
   try_files $uri$args $uri$args $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;
   ...
```

It loads well when I go to `domain.com/app/` but when I do something like `domain.com/app/?query_params` or `domain.com/app/route` it just serves the main page `("domain.com/app/")`, like the `angular-routing` is not working.

Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a beginning of an html tag, while something in plain text was expected.

Comment: You will need to tell angular what the folder is in whcih it is served. You can build with ng build —prod —base-href /app/